# Accessing $_POST array from objects called on page

Tags: php

I have a page that receives POST data from a form. I also have a form validation class that attempts to access the $_POST array when a FormValidation object is created on the page. However, the FormValidation object does not seem to have access to the $_POST array. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

EDIT: Added code :)

This code is from register.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
var_dump($_POST);

$errors = validate_form();

if(count($errors) > 0)
{
    display($errors);
}
else
{
    act();
}
}
else
{
display();
}

function validate_form()
{
$validator = new FormValidation('POST');

$validator->add_field('first_name', 'First Name');
$validator->add_field('last_name', 'Last Name');
$validator->add_field('email_address', 'Email Address');
$validator->add_field('password', 'Password');
$validator->add_field('password_confirmation', 'Password Confirmation');

$validator->add_rule('first_name', 'required');
$validator->add_rule('last_name', 'required');
$validator->add_rule('email_address', 'required');
$validator->add_rule('email_address', 'is_valid_scarsdaleschools_email');
$validator->add_rule('password', 'required');
$validator->add_rule('password_confirmation', 'required');
$validator->add_rule('password_confirmation', 'matches', array('password', 'Password'));


return $validator->validate();
}
```

The form validation code looks like this

```
class FormValidation
{
var $fields;
var $rules; //Associative array that maps field_name to array of rules
var $errors;

var $form_method_type;

function FormValidation($form_method_type)
{
    $this->form_method_type = strtoupper($form_method_type);

    $this->fields = array(); //maps fields to field labels
    $this->rules = array();
    $this->errors = array();
}

function validate() 
{   
    foreach(array_keys($this->fields) as $field_name)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($field_name, $this->rules))
        {
            continue;
        }
        foreach(array_keys($this->rules[$field_name]) as $rule_name)
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $rule_name), $this->rules[$field_name][$rule_name]);
        }
    }

    return $this->errors;
}

function add_field($field_name, $field_label)
{
    $this->fields[$field_name] = $field_label;
}

function add_rule($field_name, $rule_name, $parameters=array())
{                                                           
    if(!isset($this->rules[$field_name]))
    {
        $this->rules[$field_name] = array();
    }

    array_unshift($parameters, $field_name, $this->fields[$field_name]);
    $this->rules[$field_name][$rule_name] = $parameters;
}

function var_isset($field_name)
{
    global ${'$_' . $this->form_method_type};
    var_dump(${'$_' . $this->form_method_type}[$field_name]);
    return isset(${'$_' . $this->form_method_type}[$field_name]);
}

function get_value($field_name)
{
    global ${'$_' . $this->form_method_type};
    return ${'$_' . $this->form_method_type}[$field_name];
}

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////RULES//////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function required($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if(!$this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label is a required field";
    }
}

function is_valid_email($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!validEmail($this->get_value($field_name)))
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label requires a valid email address";
        }
    }
}

function is_alpha($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!ctype_alpha($this->get_value($field_name)))
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label requires alphabetical characters only";
        }
    }
}

function is_alphanumeric($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!ctype_alnum($this->get_value($field_name)))
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label requires alphanumeric characters only";
        }
    }
}

function is_integer_number($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!is_int($this->get_value($field_name)) || preg_match('[-+]?[0-9]+', $this->get_value($field_name)) == 0)
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must be an integer";
        }
    }
}

function is_float_number($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!is_float($this->get_value($field_name)) || preg_match('[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+', $this->get_value($field_name)) == 0)
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must be a number";
        }
    }
}

function is_valid_scarsdaleschools_email($field_name, $field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(!validEmail($this->get_value($field_name)))
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label requires a valid email address";
        }

        $email = $this->get_value($field_name);

        if(!(endsWith($email, 'scarsdaleschools.org', $case=false) || endsWith($email, 'scarsdaleschools.com', $case=false) || endsWith($email, 'scarsdaleschools.k12.ny.edu', $case=false)))
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label requires a Scarsdale Schools email address";
        }
    }
}

function max_length($field_name, $field_label, $max_length)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(strlen($this->get_value($field_name)) > $max_length)
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label cannot be longer than $max_length characters";
        }
    }
}

function min_length($field_name, $field_label, $min_length)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name))
    {
        if(strlen($this->get_value($field_name)) > $min_length)
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must be at least $min_length characters";
        }
    }
}

function matches($field_name, $field_label, $match_field_name, $match_field_label)
{
    if($this->var_isset($field_name) && !$this->var_isset($match_field_name))
    {
        $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must match $match_field_label";
    }
    elseif(!$this->var_isset($field_name) && $this->var_isset($match_field_name))
    {
        $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must match $match_field_label";
    }
    if($this->var_isset($field_name) && $this->var_isset($match_field_name))
    {
        if(strcmp($this->get_value($field_name), $this->get_value($match_field_name)) != 0)
        {
            $this->errors[$field_name] = "$field_label must match $match_field_label";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal, meaning that it's available in any scope at any time.  As long you are still in the same script to which the form data was posted, `$_POST` should be available anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in your code.  What you were writing was essentially `$$_POST`.  You'll need to remove the extra dollar sign from the variable name (corrected methods below).  In addition, you needn't worry about calling `global $_POST;` as $_POST is a superglobal, or automatic global.

**Update:** Retrieving `$_POST` via `${'_' . $this->form_method_type}` does not seem to work.  The code I sent you works OUTSIDE of the class, but not inside.  I wanted to make sure you understood my findings, and the distinction.  So while ${'_' . $formMethodType} works outside of the class, inside you'll have to use something like this:

```
const TYPE_POST = 'POST';
const TYPE_GET = 'GET';
const TYPE_SESSION = 'SESSION';
const TYPE_SERVER = 'SERVER';
const TYPE_REQUEST = 'REQUEST';

public $fields = array();
public $rules = array();
public $errors = array();

public function __construct($formMethodType)
{
    $r = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $constants = $r->getConstants();

    $formMethodType = strtoupper($formMethodType);
    if (!array_key_exists('TYPE_' . $formMethodType, $constants)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Could not find type matching $formMethodType : ' . $formMethodType);
    }
    $this->form_method_type = $formMethodType;
}

public function var_isset($field_name)
{
    $values = $this->get_values();
    var_dump($values[$field_name]);
    return isset($values[$field_name]);
}

public function get_value($field_name)
{
    $values = $this->get_values();
    return $values[$field_name];
}

public function get_values()
{
    switch ($this->form_method_type) {
        case self::TYPE_POST:
            $values = $_POST;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_GET:
            $values = $_GET;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_REQUEST:
            $values = $_REQUEST;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_SERVER:
            $values = $_SERVER;
            break;
        case self::TYPE_SESSION:
            $values = $_SESSION;
            break;
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: When I tried your change for var_isset I got the following error:
`Notice: Undefined variable: _POST in /Users/nick/Sites/CompLabSite/includes/formvalidation.php on line 58 NULLL` When I return to the old code a var_dump shows `Notice: Undefined variable: $_POST in /Users/nick/Sites/CompLabSite/includes/formvalidation.php on line 58 NULL` This leads me to believe that the old way was at least trying to access the right variable, but it doesn't seem to be global for some reason. :-/

Comment: @nickles I am positive that this method of pulling from $_POST works.  You have to trust me when I say your original code was trying to pull from `$$_POST`.

Comment: @nickles Can you test this code? `$_POST['test'] = 'test123';
$var = 'POST';
var_dump(${'_' . $var});`

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you using?  I successfully tested this code in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @webjawns.com I'm running PHP 5.3. Give me a second to run the test code there.

Comment: @webjawns.com Running the test code there throws a slew of this error:
`Notice: Undefined variable: _POST in /Users/nick/Sites/CompLabSite/includes/formvalidation.php on line 60 NULL`

Edit: Oddly enough (or not), running `var_dump($_POST);` directly spit out the correct array.

Comment: Did you run the exact code that I gave you?  Not inside the class, but outside the class?

Comment: @nickles let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/999/discussion-between-webjawns-com-and-nickles)

Comment: I think I know what is going on here.  Inside of a class, ${'_POST'} in ANY form does not appear to work, so I have another approach for you.  Give me one sec to write it up.

Comment: Just made some changes that will make your class a bit stronger, and more secure. Check them out!  ...and I am happy to help!  I'm glad we could get this resolved for you!

Answer (score 1):

We haven't yet seen any code posted, but I'll make a recommendation about using dependency injection to get the `$_POST` data into your form validation class, rather than accessing the superglobal from inside the class.

Since you can't always rely on `$_POST` being populated correctly when you are testing your code, it is advisable to inject the contents of `$_POST` as a parameter to the constructor of a class where it will be used.  This makes it easier to debug later on.

```
class MyClass {
  // Public property to hold post array data 
  public $postdata;

  // constructor receives $_POST as a parameter
  function __construct($param1, $param2, $postdata) {
    //
    $this->postdata  = $postdata;
  }
}

// Instantiate the class with $_POST injected
$x = new MyClass($a, $b, $_POST);
```

**ADDENDUM after code posted**

I don't see any method in your class that actually calls the `get_value()` method when validating.  It's unclear if you are ever accessing the contents of `$_POST` in that class at all other than in the `var_isset()` and `get_value()` methods.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!
I have a bunch of rules that use both methods. I snipped the rules out since I found that the get_value() method was not able to see the $_POST data. I'll post them all though.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This should work for $_REQUEST and $_POST the mysql_real_escape_string
 * was added to escape urls. It is best not to allow URLs as parameters.
 */
foreach( $_POST as $key=> $val)
{
  ${$key} = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}
```